# How to compile a fla file which need some param from html

Tags: flash, actionscript, parameter-passing

In html file, I add params like this:

`<param name="FlashVars" value="myVar=1" />`

In fla file,I load the param like this:

```
stage.loaderInfo.parameters
```

here comes the problem, each time I compile the file, the swf file is reporting errors because of url is null.

so how can I do this right?

Answer (score 0):

When reading in the property from stage.loaderInfo.parameters, simply set a default value as a fallback so it will work in testing.

```
var something = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.myVar || 1;
```

When myVar evaluates to false, it will pick up the default instead.